# A question about semigroups in a Heisenberg group

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, regularity, semigroups-of-operators, heisenberg-groups

I'm trying to understand if the regularity of solutions in Heisenberg groups works like in the Euclidean case. So far I haven't found any results, so I'm trying to check if the Regularity Theorems work. There is a theorem in A. Pazy - Semigroups of Linear Operators and Applications to Partial Differential Equations (chapter 4 theorem 3.2) which states that for the problem
$$u_t = Au(t)+f(t), \qquad u(0)=x$$
with $A$ infinitesimal generator of an analytic semigroup and $f$ Holder continuous a mild solution is a classical solution.

In an attempt to try to imitate this result for Heisenberg spaces, I sought some information about the semigroup generated by the sublaplacian. I found: Hunt's theorem (in  Semigroups of measures on a Lie group), tells us that the sub-Laplacian is the restriction to $\overline{C_0^2}$ of the infinitesimal generator of a unique, strongly continuous, contractive, positivity-preserving semigroup of operators on $C_0$. But I didn't find anything about this semigroup being analytic. He is? Or is it possible to reproduce this result of Holder regularity without the semigroup being analytic